# How to access and manipulate tables when using native unit tests?

Tags: smart-contract, unit-tests

I am trying to write unit tests for functions in a smart contract that require access to tables within the smart contract. I tried to set this up using the `hello_test.cpp` code as a base and when I get to the point where I access an iterator the a table element I get the error:

`unsupported intrinsic`

Does anyone have any idea how I can create a certain state for my tables and then run a specific function to see the impact that the table states has on that function in that moment?

Answer (score 1):

Native tester is not available yet unless you implement intrinsics by yourself. You can find partial implementations of intrinsics from development branch named by testerXXX, (eosio.cdt/tools/tester/eosio-tester.cpp), but not recommend to use them now.